# utc time string convert to Unix timestamp, and then convert back to utc date time string. But the result is not matched with the original one

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, utc, python-datetime

I expect 'utc' and 'utc_str_back' should be the same time, but result is diferent. Here is the code:

```
#input
utc='2023-09-20T05:04:54'

#calculation
utc_time = datetime.strptime(utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
utc_dn = utc_time.timestamp()
utc_back = datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_dn, tz=pytz.utc)
utc_str_back = utc_back.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')

#output
utc_str_back ='2023-09-19 21:04:54 UTC'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

naive datetime in Python refers to *local time*, not UTC. Therefore,

```py
utc_time = datetime.strptime(utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

is misleading; `utc_time` will be interpreted as local time. That goes wrong in the moment you call

```py
utc_dn = utc_time.timestamp()
```

The `timestamp` method will convert the datetime to UTC, then calculate Unix time (which refers to UTC).

---

***How to fix it***

[docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects)

> A naive object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects.

Your application requires exactly that. So use aware datetime to avoid ambiguities. EX:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

#input
utc='2023-09-20T05:04:54'

#calculation
utc_time = datetime.strptime(utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
utc_dn = utc_time.timestamp()
utc_back = datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_dn, tz=timezone.utc)
utc_str_back = utc_back.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')

#output
print(utc_str_back)
# 2023-09-20 05:04:54 UTC
```

---

p.s. [pytz is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Comment: The problem has been solved! Thank you for noticing about the pytz, so should I use timezone for replacing pytz in future?

Comment: @QinghuanLi `timezone` from the datetime module is mostly use only to set UTC; if you're handling time zones, you can use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) since Python 3.9.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again. If I want to convert into some local time zone, how can I change the time zone string (maybe from timezonefinder like local_timezone = tf.timezone_at(lng=Longitude, lat=Latitude)) into the tzinfo subclass which can be recognized by datetime? I know pytz could do (pytz.timezone(local_timezone_str)), but is there any better solution? Thanks!

Comment: I have found the way:
local_timezone = ZoneInfo(local_timezone_str)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the input is already considered to be in UTC, you should not convert it to UTC. When you are calling `utc_back = datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_dn, tz=pytz.utc)` you are "UTCizing" the value.

Fix:

```
#input
utc='2023-09-20T05:04:54'

#calculation
utc_time = datetime.strptime(utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
utc_dn = utc_time.timestamp()
utc_back = datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_dn) # <- modified
utc_str_back = utc_back.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

Comment: this is right for the wrong reason. `utc_dn` will not contain the correct Unix time for datetime '2023-09-20T05:04:54' UTC.

Comment: Yes, it returns right outputs, but I should avoid ambiguities of the time zone as Fatjon suggested.